# Seismic attenuation in mixed gas/water

Tags: seismology

Imagine I set off an airgun in the ocean and I measure the far-field signature.
Then I do the same thing shortly after introducing tiny gas bubbles into the water, and mixing them well.

Are there measurements of the Q factor for the mixed phase?